# Using pyspark in Zeppelin with python3 on Spark 2.1.0

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, python-3.5, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to run pyspark in Zeppelin and python3 (3.5) against Spark 2.1.0.  I have got the pyspark shell up and running with python3 but flipping over to Zeppelin connecting to the same local cluster gives:

```
Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.5 than that in driver 2.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions
```

I have modified the default spark-env.sh as follows: (unmodified lines omitted for brevity)

```
SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
SPARK_MASTER_HOST="localhost"
SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080
SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/ipython
```

Staring things up `./bin/pyspark` and all is good in the shell.

Zeppelin config has been modified in zeppelin-site.xml only to move the ui port away from 8080 to 8666.  `zeppelin-env.sh' has been modified as follows: (showing only mods/additions)

```
export MASTER=spark://127.0.0.1:7077
export SPARK_APP_NAME=my_zeppelin-mf
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/ipython
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
```

I've tried using Anaconda but python 3.6 is currently creating issues with Spark.  Also, I've used a bunch of combinations of the above config settings w/o success.

There is a setting referenced in the configs `zeppelin.pyspark.python` which defaults to `python` but it is unclear from the docs how/where to adjust that to python3.  To help eliminate OSX specifics, I was able to replicate this failure on LinuxMint 18.1 as well.

- Running local on OSX 10.11.6
- Spark is 2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7
- Zeppelin 0.7.0-bin-all

So I've been rifling through the Zeppelin docs and the Internet trying to find the proper config setting to get Zeppelin to run as a 3.5 driver.  With hope I'm missing something obvious, but I cannot seem to track this one down.  Hoping someone has done this successfully and can help identify my error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naturally, something worked right after posting this...

In the Zeppelin config at ./conf/interpreter.json, for one of my notebooks I found the config:

```
 "properties": {
    ...
    "zeppelin.pyspark.python": "python",
    ... 
 }
```

Changing this to:

```
 "properties": {
    ...
    "zeppelin.pyspark.python": "python3",
    ... 
 }
```

`(Combined with the same settings as above)`

Has had the desired effect of getting the notebook work with python 3.5.  However, this seems a bit clunky/hacky and I suspect there is a more elegant way to do this.  So I won't call this a solution/answer, but more of a work around.

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to set the `%pyspark` interpreter to use python 3 through the Zeppelin UI is the following (tested on apache/zeppelin docker container).

1. Click on your user menu
2. Click on `Interpreter` menu item
3. Search for `spark` interpreter
4. set the `zeppelin.pyspark.python` config property to `python3`
5. Click `Save`
6. Click on `Restart` at the top right corner to restart the interpreter

You can now check that the version of python opening a Notebook and running the following code:

```
%pyspark
import sys
sys.version_info
```

You should see something like this as output

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

You must also set the PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_PYTHON_DRIVER to python3 like this (example using apache/zeppelin docker container assuming zeppelin as container name):

```
docker exec -it zeppelin bash
cd /zeppelin/conf
cp zeppelin-env.sh.template zeppelin-env.sh
cat <<EOF >> zeppelin-env.sh
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3
EOF
# Now, press Ctrl+d to exit the container
docker restart zeppelin
```

Now everything has been set to run pyspark with python3

Answer (score 0):

If you use HDP sandbox also see

https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/146508/how-to-use-alternate-python-version-for-spark-in-z.html

Might also work for Python 3 if adapted accordingly:

```
The following steps are for Python 2.7.14 version:

Download and Install Python 2.7.14 in /usr/local/Python-2.7.14:
    # wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.14/Python-2.7.14.tar.bz2
    # tar xvf Python-2.7.14.tar.bz2
    # chown –R root:root Python-2.7.14
    # cd Python-2.7.14
    # ./configure
    # make altinstall prefix=/usr/local/Python-2.7.14 exec-prefix=/usr/local/Python-2.7.14
Add following values in spark-env template under advanced spark-env section of Spark configuration in Ambari UI and restart Spark:
    export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/Python-2.7.14/bin/python2.7
    export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/local/Python-2.7.14/bin/python2.7
    export SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV="PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/Python-2.7.14/bin/python2.7”
Change the following value in Spark Interpreter configuration in Zeppelin, save and restart the Interpreter:
    zeppelin.pyspark.python = /usr/local/Python-2.7.14/bin/python2.7 (Default value is python)
Add and execute the following in notebook for validation:

    %spark.pyspark
    import sys
    print (sys.version)

The following should be the output from above notebook:

    2.7.14 (default, Oct 4 2017, 09:43:59)
    [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)]
```